# Explanation for the regular expression for the set of all string over the alphabet {0,1}

Tags: regular-expressions

Why does set of all strings over the alphabet {0,1} is represented by (0+1)*? As per my understanding (0+1) means either 0 and 1 and * means 0 or more occurrence of the given string. Now when we do (0+1)* it looks like we have to select either 0 or 1 and do a * on that so the resulting should be something like

***$\{\epsilon,0,1,00,11,000\dots\}$***

but why is it following?

***$\{\epsilon,0,1,00,01,10,11\dots\}$***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Klenee operator and it means all number of $(0 + 1)(0 + 1)\cdots$ with all possible length. As $(0+1)^{10}$ means $(0+1)(0+1)\cdots(0+1)$ for ten times. Hence, All possible combinations of $0$ and $1$ are comming in $(0+1)^*$.

In the other words by the definition, it means the union of all $(0 + 1)^i$ for all $i$ from $0$ to $\infty$.